# Array and simple queries using vector

Tags: c++

[image]**I am solving "https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/array-and-simple-queries/copy-from/145435292" problem. while solving this problem I got stuck in one logical error.**

I have tried to solve this problem in this way.

```cpp
int main() 
{ 
    long long int i,j,k,l,x,n,m,a[3],c;
    vector<long long int> g1; 
    cin>>n>>m;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>x;
        g1.push_back(x); 
    } 
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            cin>>a[j];
        }
        if(a[0]==1)
        {
            c=0;
            g1.insert(g1.begin(),g1.begin()+(a[1]-1),g1.begin()+a[2]);
            c=a[2]-a[1];
            c++;
            g1.erase(g1.begin() + a[1]+(c-1), g1.begin() + a[2]+c);
        }
        else 
        {
            g1.insert(g1.end(),g1.begin()+(a[1]-1),g1.begin()+a[2]);
            g1.erase(g1.begin() + a[1]-1, g1.begin() + a[2]);
        }

        cout<<"\n";
        for (auto y = g1.begin(); y != g1.end(); ++y) 
        cout << *y << " "; 
    }
    // c=g1[0]-g1[n-1];
    // if(c<0)
    // {
    //     c=c*-1;
    // }
    // cout<<c<<"\n";
    // cout<<"\n";
    // for (auto y = g1.begin(); y != g1.end(); ++y) 
        // cout << *y << " "; 
    return 0; 
}
```

The input format is-

1. n,m: where n is the total number and m is the total number of queries.
2. The next line is n numbers.
3. The next lines contain m queries.

   1. Type 1 queries are represented as `1 i j` : Modify the given array by removing elements from i to j and adding them to the front.
   2. Type 2 queries are represented as `2 i j` : Modify the given array by removing elements from i to j and adding them to the back

For Input:

> 7 2
>   1 2 3 4 5 6 7
>   1 3 6
>   1 3 6

My output is:

> 3 4 5 6 1 2 7
>   5 6 3 4 3 4 7

But my output should be:

> 3 4 5 6 1 2 7
>   5 6 1 2 3 4 7

Please help me out.

Comment: I've partially reformated the code but the missing line breaks in comments are unfortunately left to fix by hand.

Comment: I'm going to recommend that you declare your variables where they are initialized, rather than at the beginning, and that you give them descriptive names (with the exception of the loop counters i and j, since those names are kinda tradition at this point).  It's impossible for anyone to follow the code otherwise

Comment: I'd guess you're not allowed use the same vector as both source and destination when inserting. That's where it's going wrong on the second pass for me at least. If I make a copy of the vector to use as the insert source then it works fine. Don't know why it just works for the first instruction though. (I expect someone can give you an answer with a quote from the standard.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding this line:

```
    g1.insert(g1.begin(),g1.begin()+(a[1]-1),g1.begin()+a[2]);
//  ^^        ^^         ^^ It's the same
```

I can't find a specific quote from the Standard, but in [22.3.11.5](https://eel.is/c++draft/vector.modifiers) [*Containers.sequences.vector.modifiers* (insert, emplace_back, emplace, push_back)] it's specified:

> Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity.
>   Reallocation invalidates all the references, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements in the sequence, as well as the past-the-end iterator. If no reallocation happens, then references, pointers, and iterators before the insertion point remain valid but those at or after the insertion point, including the past-the-end iterator, are invalidated.

The [cppreference.com](https://eel.is/c++draft/vector.modifiers) page about [`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) has the following clarifications (emphasis mine)

> ```
> template< class InputIt >
> iterator insert( const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last );
> ```
>
> Inserts elements at the specified location in the container.
>   ...
>   The *behavior is undefined* if first and last are iterators into `*this`.
>   ...
>   **first**, **last**   -   the range of elements to insert, *can't be iterators into container for which insert is called.*

It's also worth noting that inserting at the beginnning and then erasing the elements in the middle of a vector may be a rather inefficient method.

The expected results could be easily achieved using another algorithm, [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate):

```
if (a[0] == 1)
{ 
    std::rotate(
        g1.begin(),               // First element of the range to be left rotated.
        g1.begin() + (a[1] - 1),  // Element which will become the first
        g1.begin() + a[2]         // Last element of the range to be modified.
    );
}
else
{
    std::rotate(
        g1.begin() + (a[1] - 1),
        g1.begin() + a[2],
        g1.end()
    );
}
```